# Is "a-blink" an adjectival form of "blink" in old days?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, parts-of-speech, derivational-morphology

> Under his breath, with a furtive exultation, he began once again the paean of victory and devastation.  And presently his eyes were rewarded: out through that doorway came a long, low, yellow-and-brown beast, with eyes **a-blink** at the waning daylight, and dark wet stains around the fur of jaws and throat.

I can't find this "a-blink" in the dictionary, so I presume this word is no longer in use. Is it an adjectival form of "blink"? And could it be replaced by *blinking* these days?

Comment: ***a-*** In native (derived from Old English) words, it most commonly represents Old English an "on"  as in alive, asleep, abroad, afoot, etc., forming adjectives and adverbs from nouns; but it also can be Middle English of, as in anew, abreast (1590s); or a reduced form of Old English past participle prefix ge-, as in aware; *or the Old English intensive a-, as in arise, awake, ashame, marking a verb as momentary, a single event.*
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a-&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: And, yes, you could therefore replace it with 'blinking', and even drop the 'with': 'eyes blinking in the waning daylight' sounds fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a prepositional verb, formed with the Old English-derived proclitic "a" as in *a-hunting we will go.*

[See definition 5.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/a-#Etymology_2)